# Question about Bert Mendelson definition of disconnectedness

Tags: general-topology

I need help picturing the spaces, I found one that abides by its rules by seems wrong.

Lemma 2.3 Let A be a subspace of a topological space X. Then A is disconnected if and only if there exist two open susbsets P and Q of X such that

A $\subset$ P $\cup$ Q

P $\cap$ Q $\subset$ C(A)

and P $\cap$ A $\ne$ $\emptyset$ , Q $\cap$ A $\ne$ $\emptyset$.

By going by the last requirement, is it possible for intersection of P and A be A; Q and A be A? Assume Left circle is P, right circle is Q, and the intersection as A.

[image]

The proof assumes this picture instead, [image: name] , where the space between P' and Q is C(P') and that the line between P and C(P') is the line that separates P from Q.

Comment: What does "C" represent? $\;$

Answer (score 1):

$A\: \subset \: P\cap Q \;\;$ and $\;\; P\cup Q \: \subset \: C(A)$

$\implies$
$A \: = \: A\cap A \: \subseteq \: A\cap P\cap Q \: \subseteq \: A\cap P \: \subseteq \: A\cap (P\cup Q) \: \subseteq \: A\cap C(A) \: = \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$

$A\: \subset \: P\cap Q \;\;$ and $\;\; P\cup Q \: \subset \: C(A) \;\;$ and $\;\; P\cap A \: \neq \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$

$\implies$
$A \: = \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \;\;$ and $\;\; P\cap A \: \neq \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$

$\implies$
$\{\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \: = \: P\cap \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \: = \: P\cap A \: \neq \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$

Therefore, by the definition you gave, subspaces are *never* disconnected.

Perhaps you should replace the definition you gave with the one on [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=FWFmoEUJSwkC&pg=PA114).

Comment: My bad, I meant the definition you had linked to. Thanks for the answer to my err though.